# How to copy bookmarks of included PDFs?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, pdfpages, bookmarks, pax

I want to create a document, which uses pages of other documents, while keeping the original bookmarks. There are some laconic answers pointing towards `pax`. The README of the `pax` package lists the following usage instructions:

Run `java -cp pax.jar;pdfbox.jar pax.PDFAnnotExtractor bookmark.pdf`. I substituted `;` here for `:`, because of the Windows shell and the bookmark documentation for "usrguide.pdf". This step seems to work fine as the shell prints only: "* Processing file `bookmark.pdf' ...", returns after that and "bookmark.pax" contains roughly 17,500 lines.

Running pdfLaTeX twice with MikTeX on the `test.tex` given below produces no errors either. The resulting PDF, however, lacks all bookmarks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=1in,
  vmargin=1in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfpages} % pdfpages loads graphicx

\usepackage{pax}

\iffalse
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    filebordercolor={1 1 0},
  }
\fi

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x1]{bookmark}
\end{document}
```

Am I missing something in the usage of `pax`? Is there another package better suited for my purposes?

Comment: Never used `pax`, but why disabling `hyperref`? No bookmarks without `hyperref`.

Comment: @AlexG `pax` reinserts pre-existent bookmarks extracted via `pdfannotextractor`. `hyperef` is required to manage new annotations/links and to change default border colors of links.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: A full example using a pax workflow is available at https://github.com/gi-ev/LNI-proceedings. Maybe, this helps? The typical issue with pax is that one does one pdflatex run too less.

Comment: In my experience `pax` works well for preserving clickable inner links as inserted by `hyperref`, but it removes the pdf bookmarks corresponding to the sections and I couldn't figure out how to preserve these. I would be very interested in a solution!